# Organization of iPhone app source code before submission to Apple

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am about to submit my iPhone app to the app store, and I am wondering: is there a standard for how I organize my source code (the directories, the naming of the directories, which file goes to which folder, etc.)? Actually, do I even submit the source code to Apple at all? Maybe I missed it, but I do not think source code was mentioned in the guideline.

Comment: Your post contained two unrelated questions; ideally on SO there is only one question per post. It would be best if the second was posted separately, although it is already answered by this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546046/check-for-private-api-usage-yourself, among others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You do not submit your source code to Apple, only the binary application signed with your distribution certificate.
2. Some static analysis of your binary is done when you submit it via the Application Loader app. In theory, undocumented API calls should be caught at this time. If nothing is caught, Apple will surely catch them and let you know.

In general, undocumented API calls are prefixed with an underscore. Not all follow this convention, but you could search the source code for methods and functions that begin with `_` or `__`. Google searching any questionable code symbols will likely yield at least some information about whether the method or function is supported and what it does. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First point has been answered already.

For the second point I would like to suggest the usage of the Xcode feature called "Validate Built Product". This option will perform the same tests on your app the Apple themselves do once you submit your app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not have to submit any of your source code to Apple.
2. There is no real way to check without going through all of the code, just submit it, and see what happens !

Answer (score 0):

1.Code is not submitted to apple. Only binary of the app is submitted. You can send your app flow separately from your iTunes connect account.

1. Make sure your app obey all the points of app review notes. specially data storage policy.